# Ubuntu 14.04 hangs after logging in, not a video problem

Tags: login

I was recovering some data off a usb drive and Ubuntu warned of 0 space left. I emptied the trash and shut down.

Turned back on and after login it just hangs. Thought it might be a space issue so <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F2</kbd> and deleted a 1 GB file and emptied the trash.

Rebooted and still hangs after login. Is there a log file somewhere that will tell me why it is hanging? Everything worked perfectly prior to this.

Answer (score 0):

Dropped down to command line and found SDA5 was full. Removed 30GB of files and could log in again.